# Хочу сделать команду autoclear и присвоить ее каналу, но не пойму как это реализовать? Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Хочу сделать команду autoclear и присвоить ее каналу, саму команду уже тысячу раз нашел, но она не работает и не удаляет ничего, хоть она и сделана для всех каналов, но я ее исключил из списка и пытаюсь написать свою, но не выходит так как только начал изучать питон и начал изучать с Бота для дискорда.
Помогите разобраться с проблемой.
Вот код:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Я запущен!')
    bot.loop.create_task(status_task())
    channel = bot.get_channel(972431181624791060)  # replace `channel_id` with an actual channel ID
    await channel.purge(limit=0)  # change `x` accordingly...
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял, почему вы пишете, что хотите создать команду, но прикладываете код с ивентом.
Конкретно в вашем коде ошибка в том, что limit=0, то есть вы удаляете 0 сообщений.

```
@bot.command()
async def delete(ctx, amount: int = None):
    if ctx.channel.id == ид канала:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    else:
        await ctx.send('В этом канале нельзя использовать данную команду!')
```

Answer (score 0):

я разобрался уже со всем
Если кому нужно, то вот

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message) # чтобы команды работали
    if message.channel.id == 972431181624791060:
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
        await message.delete()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Я запущен!')
    bot.loop.create_task(status_task())
    channel = bot.get_channel(972431181624791060)
    await channel.purge(limit=0)
    await schedule_daily_message1()
```